# What Content-Type should binary data use?

Tags: http-headers, content-type

My webservice used to take a simple JSON body and so I was passing a `Content-Type: application/json` and expecting that on the server side.  Now I've implemented encryption of the body so I'm not sure what I should do with the headers.  It's not actually JSON any longer.

Answer (score 8):

`application/octet-stream` might be suitable in this case. But when ssl is available why do you have to do one more encryption?

Comment: Because the client doesn't want people to be able to see details of the payload that are being sent back and forth.  If it's not encrypted, they can just look at it in the developer window of chrome, for example.

Comment: So, you use Public key to encrypt the data? what happens if the user uses developer tools to place a break point before the call to encryption happens?

Comment: Um...it's an angular application.  They can't just set a breakpoint somewhere as they don't have the actual source code, right?

Comment: The code is obfuscated (minified). But nothing will stop a determined person to reverse engineer it. The point I wanted to highlight is, we dont have a control on what happens in the client browser.

Comment: So I wasted an entire day getting libsodium to work :(